# Can't make Stripe API call from connected account

Tags: stripe-payments, invoice

I'm trying to call `invoices.list` https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list in order to see all the paid invoices from a specific connected account. The issue happens when I try to specify the connected account the call is made for. I'm trying to authenticate as detailed here https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header, but I'm getting the following error: Error: Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object]). Did you mean to pass an options object? See https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/wiki/Passing-Options Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Here's the way I'm calling the method:

```
 stripe.invoices.list(
{ status: 'paid' },
{ stripeAccount: 'connected_account_id' },
(err, invoices) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.json(invoices);
}
```

);

I've tried passing the `stripeAccount` value in many different ways but no luck..

Comment: Which version of the Stripe API are you using, and which version of the stripe-node library?

Comment: I see you've asked in https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/799 as well so someone from the team will follow up there.

Comment: @taintedzodiac UPDATE: I've found the issue, and I think it's in fact version related. If I use `stripe_account` instead of `stripeAccount`, the response is obtained successfully. I'm using Stripe: 1.2.2 and stripe-node: 7.4.0